# Make List 2 Columns

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the footer of http://www.animefushigi.com/, I am trying to make the affiliate list 2 columns, as 1 is too long.

The code is as follows

```
    <ul class="none"><li><span>Affiliates<em>&nbsp;</em></span></li>
<li>link 1</li>
<li>link 2</li>
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can make nested ul like this:

```
<ul class="none">
<li><span>Affiliates<em>&nbsp;</em></span></li>
 <ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li>link 3</li>
  <li>link 4</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, i'm such a clutz >.< i made a nested ul with li at 45% width, and they made themselves into columns.

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this using only css: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/ThvUJ/ (wont work in ie lte 8)

but i think the best way to do it will be making js script, which will count li elements and add `</ul><ul>` if necessary. (example: http://jsfiddle.net/seler/ThvUJ/3/)

Answer (score 2):

If the order doesn't matter (and I'm assuming it doesn't because you're using an unordered list), you could achieve this effect with your current HTML. Just float your list elements in such a way that only two of them can fit per line. Below is a quick example of what I mean:

```
ul { 
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 90px; /* 100 - 5 - 5 */
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
li a {
    width: 90px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your footer to be a specific height, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/NfMPX/

Basically, set the height of the `ul` and float and set a width for the `li`s and they will automatically wrap.